# Is it ok to use map() in python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is it ok / good style to use python built in functions like `map()` in unit tests?

for example instead of writing an individual assert for all test cases something like:

```
def double_x(x):
    return x*2

def test_double_x():
    orig_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    expected_vals = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
    assert list(map(double_x, orig_vals)) == expected_vals
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem, but like anywhere else, a list comprehension may be preferable.

```
assert [double_x(x) for x in orig-vals] == expected_vals
```

Individual assertions, though, may make it easier to identify the failed test.

```
for x, y in zip(orig_vals, expected_vals):
    z = double_x(x)
    assert z == y, f'double_x({x}) returned {z}, not {y} as expected'
```